# Node.js - "which node" returns wrong path

Tags: node.js, npm, config, filepath

I was messing around with my node.js config, following a guide on moving the globals folder to somewhere more appropriate.

I eventually wound up in a position where I couldn't install anything with NPM. So I tried "which npm". This returns:

["which npm"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JlC6.png)

The file path is wrong, my the C:\ drive is not being entered properly. Obviously, this is wrong. But I couldn't figure out how to change this. Out of curiosity, I tried "which node":

["which node"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dFta.png)

Which is also wrong. I can't edit the prefix file because npm won't let me do anything. I've tried PC restarts, complete uninstalls, adding the real folder path to the $PATH but nothing is working.

Would appreciate some help!

Comment: Run `which npm` in Windows console - it will point to the correct address. You are using something that tries to be compatible with POSIX standard -  aren't you?

Comment: 'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: `where node` - for Windows, `which node` for POSIX, sorry for that

Comment: It looks like you're using a cygwin shell on windows which is why it reports the C drive as /c/.  What is the error that npm is giving you, and what did you do to change the node.js config?

Comment: npm isn't giving me an error. I left an npm install command running for around 20 minutes with no output or error. Is there a log I can copy to you?

in the config, I changed the prefix to be a different folder: C:\users\user\node_modules\globals

Comment: When trying to change the prefix, the same situation occurs. Nothing is outputted and nothing gets changed.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, I delete the .npmrc file in the home directory (windows: C:\user\username), uninstalled and re-installed node.

Things are working fine now.